# Android Studio not showing logs

Tags: android, android-studio, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-logcat

I recently updated OS of my phone(Lenovo K3 Note) to Android Marshmallow(API level 23) after that I'm not able to see any logs related to any application which is running on the phone. I'm not able to check on any other device which have Marshmallow but I tried working on emulator which have Android Marshmallow(23) and everything is working fine. Everything else is working fine if I use any other device which have Lollipop or lower version. I'm not sure what is wrong. Please help.

Comment: have you tried to 'Debug' your app?

Comment: Check if Debugging is enabled on your Developer Options. If you're using Windows, update your phone's drivers.

Comment: @MounirElfassi  I also tried to Debug but still not showing any logs.

Comment: @RosárioPereiraFernandes Debugging is enabled and I'm using mac.

Comment: On your Android Studio's Android Monitor, make sure you select your device and your application

Comment: @RosárioPereiraFernandes As i have written in the question it is working fine with all other devices which have Android Lollipop or lower and even working fine with emulator so i don't think that can be a problem.

Answer (score 2):

Restarting the devices (mobile and computer) or updating Android Studio did the trick for me. So if something like this ever happens after an update then try restarting the device.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that the update disabled developer mode?

Comment: Developer mode is on. I don't know if has something to do with update.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting the device worked for me too.

For the safer side, I did Invalidate cache and restart in android studio